# How to test if a substring from each line of File1 exists in File2

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have two files with following data

**file1:**

```
6100540301SD01        ON5330399520191104906781            2019110390678151053303995ACK          20191105
6100540301SD01        ON0403096420191104225695            2019110322569551004030964A            20191105
6005260301SD01        46460045792019110490678911059455    2019110490678951000755694BE3        1120191105
6005260301SD01        46460045792019110490679616020577    2019110490679651000764053BDJDEDH    1620191105
```

**file2:**

```
20191104
20191105
20191106
```

Since **file1** is fixed width file, the string at character position 97 to 104 is date. I want to extract the string by position from 97 to 104 and check if this exists in **file2**. If it exists, I want to copy whole line to **file3**.If its not, I want to copy it to **file4**.

I have created C++ program but it is taking long time to process the **file1** while is almost half million records. Therefore, if there is any `awk/sed` script that can be helpful, please share.

Comment: You can mark the data using `{}` button in the [editor](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58756798/edit) or prepend data lines with four spaces.

Comment: @Adeel : I don't think that you can beat C++ with awk, when it comes to speed, so probably the question is more about efficiency of your algorithm, and I would focus on this question before thinking, which programming language to use.

Comment: @Adeel : It would also help if you could give some size information for file2. For instance, the answer by Barmer is good unless file2 is huge.

Comment: @user1934428, Yes you are right algorithm matters alot. The file 2 is small one with 80 records at max. I have tried the to use random access STL containers but yes, still the algorithm can be improved as the cost of my algorithm is linear, which is high cost for large file1 with half million records.

Comment: Please post timing information.  What is too long?  It shouldn't take more than couple seconds at most.

Comment: @Adeel : In the very minimum, every record of the large file needs to be written to one of the two output files, so this gives the minimum processing time. Since you have only 80 records in the reference file, and you have string comparision for equality at fixed position, you just need in the program a Set of the 80 reference strings. All of this can be done straightforward in C++ or C, and I don't see how another programming language can make it faster. The time should be around the same as if you would just copy the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {dates[$0]; next} 
               {print > (substr($0,97,104) in dates?"file3":"file4")}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn the contents of `file2` into a regular expression like `20191104|20191106|20191106`. Then you can use `grep` to match it.

```
patterns=$(<file2)
# Replace newlines with |
pattern=${patterns//$'\n'/|}
# Put ^.{96} at the beginning so it matches starting at column 97
pattern="^.{96}($pattern)"
grep -E "$pattern" file1 > file3 # Lines that match
grep -v -E "$pattern" file1 > file4 # Lines that don't match
```

If running `grep` twice is too slow, you could use `awk`:

```
awk -v pat="$pattern" '$0 ~ pat { print >>"file3"; next} {print >>"file4"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#.*#/^.\\{96\\}&/ba#' file2 | sed -nf - -e 'w file4' -e 'b;:a;w file3' file1
```

Create a script from file2 which writes each match to file3 and any remaining lines to file4.

The first invocation of sed passes its output to the second invocation of sed which in turn is supplemented with a couple of strings of commands inline. All matches are sent to the loop holder `:a` which writes them out to file3 any that are not matched, fall through to be written to file4.